# Unable to use 'npm install' on Windows 10 (error code ECONNRESET)

Tags: node.js, networking, npm, windows-10, npm-install

I have recently installed latest version of nodejs (6.3.1) with npm version 3.10.3. I am not able to install any node package using npm install command. Initially I thought it might be related with my office network firewall settings, but I am getting similar issue on my home network. Please see attached image for error details.

Appreciate if someone can help me to find a resolution.

[image]

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to have posted an image. You can select and copy text from that command window much more easily than you can post an image, and the text is much more readable. See [this Meta post]((http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons you should **not** include images in your post unless absolutely necessary to demonstrate an issue.

Comment: Point taken @KenWhite. Thanks

Comment: `This is not [...] a problem with npm itself and is related to network connectivity. In most case you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.` Did you check your network?

Comment: npm config had bad network settings. So although I had disabled the main proxy / firewall etc. all npm commands were always going through that bad proxy. Managed to remove those bad entries finally, phew! :)

Answer (score 0):

npm config had bad network settings. So although I had disabled the main proxy / firewall etc. all npm commands were always going through that bad proxy. Managed to remove those bad entries finally, phew! :)